# One liner for n-1 cores?

Tags: bash, math, makefile, jobs

Running make with the flag `-j` uses all available cores, but this sometimes causes threads to thrash or other bad things to happen.

***In a bash script, how can I use `n-1` cores instead (only if `n>1` otherwise 1).***

There must be a simpler way to do it than this:

```
NJOBS=$((`getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN 2>/dev/null \
   || sysctl hw.ncpu  \
   || echo 2` \
   - 1))
```

Comment: By the way, `NJOBS` being all-caps isn't good form -- see the [POSIX Issue 7 spec on environment variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), which specifies that all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the operating system and shell, and that names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use. Since setting a shell variable will override any like-named environment variable, this convention applies there as well.

Comment: Even your not-so-simple solution doesn't handle the `n = 1` case or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

The entire reason your current code isn't simple is that it's trying to perform an operation that has no standardized interface across multiple operating systems. Thus, to have the best possible chance of having an approach that works on the current operating system, it goes through multiple possibilities:

- `getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` works on Linux and MacOS X, but not Solaris, FreeBSD, NetBSD, etc.
- `sysctl hw.ncpu` works on most non-Solaris systems.
- `2` is a safe default, as subtracting 1 will return a value of only one core.

To work on Solaris, one would want to add `psrinfo -p` to the list of possible fallbacks, thus making your code even *more* verbose.

---

If you're willing to compromise portability a bit (but still keep the last-ditch fallback so we don't utterly fail if run on Solaris),

```
ncores=$(sysctl hw.ncpu); njobs=$(( ncores > 1 ? (ncores - 1) : 1 ))
```

is perhaps a reasonable compromise (and handles the case, which the original didn't, where a value of `1` was successfully returned).

Answer (score 1):

The `-j` parameter in make can take an argument as to the number of cores to use.  Therefore, you can do something like:

```
CORES := $(shell grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)
JFLAG := $(shell  echo "-j$$(( $(CORES) - 1 ? $(CORES) - 1 : 1 ))"

all:
    $(MAKE) $(JFLAG) _some_sub_makefile..._
```

If you want your make to override the -j flag that was passed to it, you do something like:

```
ifeq (,$(filter DASHJSET,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))

ABSPATH := $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))

CORES := $(shell grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)
JFLAG := $(shell  echo "-j$$(( $(CORES) - 1 ? $(CORES) - 1 : 1 )))"

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(ABSPATH) $(JFLAG) DASHJSET $(MAKECMDGOALS)

.PHONY: DASHJSET

fi
```

Comment: `grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo` is entirely Linux-only -- won't work on Mac at all, for example. And the OP has yet to tag or otherwise indicate their operating system in the question.

Comment: Good point, though, about needing to handle the single-CPU case gracefully.